# problems revalidating/repainting button panel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, repaint

I've been googling for hours trying a million different subtle changes all to no avail, so I figure my best bet is to pick the brains of people more skilled than I.

I'm writing a class that loads a bunch of buttons from a database and the goal is to offer the user the ability to arrange the buttons to their liking, however, for some reason, I can't seem to get the frame to revalidate or repaint. The buttons will move around, but they will not rearrange as I have coded them to. The organization seems to be working correctly, ie the code involved in making the re arrangement when the mouse button is released, its just that the components will only stay where they are dragged and dropped, even though they are re ordered in their respective List.

The code is long, I didn't want to have to post the whole class as it may turn some people off but I don't know where I'm making the mistake so I think it would be in my best interest to post the whole thing. The main area of concern is `mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {...}` and the `repaint()`/`refresh()` method, however, there could be something that I'm missing elsewhere.

tl;dr: 
I'm basically just trying to perform a `setBounds()` after the user drags and drops the buttons in the order they want but the buttons stay in the same spot they are dragged and dropped, and won't `revalidate()` or `repaint()`. I can't even `removeAll` to clear the panel of components and reload.

Thank you in advanced. Here's my code:

```
public class AdminButtonEditor extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public AdminButtonEditor(OrderView parent) { ...
        ...
        Component[] components = buttonsPanel.getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            Component c = components[i];
            if (c instanceof JButton) {
                JButton jb = (JButton) c;
                jb.setFocusable(false);
                buttons.add(new MyJButton(...));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            buttons.get(i).addTo(editPanel);
            buttons.get(i).orderIndex=modButtonList.get(i).menuModifier.getViewOrderValue();
            buttons.get(i).idx=i;
        }
        EventHandler eh = new EventHandler();
        addWindowListener(eh);
        editPanel.addMouseMotionListener(eh);
        editPanel.addMouseListener(eh);
        contentPane.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    protected void refresh() {
        if (!buttons.isEmpty() && buttons.get(0) != null) {
            contentPane.remove(editPanel);
            editPanel.removeAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
                MyJButton s = buttons.get(i);
                s.addTo(editPanel);
            }
            contentPane.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            editPanel.repaint();
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       refresh();
       super.paint(g);
    }
    private int getSelectionIndex(int x, int y) {
        int s=-1;
        for (int i=buttons.size()-1; i>=0;i--){
            if (buttons.get(i).contains(x, y)) {
                s = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
private class EventHandler implements MouseInputListener,WindowListener, ActionListener {
    private int selectionIndex, startX, startY, lastX, lastY;
    private MyJButton selected;
    private boolean moving=false;
    ....
    ....
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (moving){
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            moving=false;
            int dropX=e.getX();
            int dropY=e.getY();
            int row = dropY/selected.height;
            int col = dropX/selected.width;
            int idx=(row*3+col)-1;
            int oldIdx=buttons.indexOf(selected);
            insertIntoList(idx,oldIdx);
         }
        if (selected!=null){
            selected.unHighLight();
            selected=null;
        }

        Collections.sort(buttons);
        for (int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++){
        //modButtonList.get(buttons.get(i).idx).menuModifier.setViewOrderValue(buttons.get(i).orderIndex);
        }
        editPanel.validate();
        repaint();
    }

    private void insertIntoList(int idx, int oldIdx) {
        MyJButton temp = buttons.get(idx);
        int tempid=buttons.get(idx).idx;
        buttons.set(idx, new MyJButton(selected.text,selected.x,selected.y,selected.width,selected.height,selected.idx));
        buttons.get(idx).orderIndex=temp.orderIndex;
        if (idx<oldIdx){
            int id;
            for (int i=oldIdx;i>idx+1;i--){
                id=buttons.get(i).orderIndex;
                buttons.set(i, new MyJButton(buttons.get(i-1).text,buttons.get(i-1).x,buttons.get(i-1).y,buttons.get(i-1).width,buttons.get(i-1).height,buttons.get(i-1).idx));
                buttons.get(i).orderIndex=id;
            }
            id = buttons.get(idx+1).orderIndex;
            buttons.set(idx+1,new MyJButton(temp.text,temp.x,temp.y,temp.width,temp.height,temp.idx));
            buttons.get(idx+1).orderIndex=id;
        } else if (idx>oldIdx) {
            int id;
            for (int i=oldIdx;i<idx-1;i++){
                id=buttons.get(i).orderIndex;
                buttons.set(i, new MyJButton(buttons.get(i+1).text,buttons.get(i+1).x,buttons.get(i+1).y,buttons.get(i+1).width,buttons.get(i+1).height,buttons.get(i+1).idx));
                buttons.get(i).orderIndex=id;
            }
            id = buttons.get(idx-1).orderIndex;
            buttons.set(idx-1,new MyJButton(temp.text,temp.x,temp.y,temp.width,temp.height,temp.idx));
            buttons.get(idx-1).orderIndex=id;;
        } else {
            buttons.get(idx).x=buttons.get(idx).originx;
            buttons.get(idx).y=buttons.get(idx).originy;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (moving) {
            Graphics g = editPanel.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(selected.getXPos(), 0, selected.getXPos(),editPanel.getWidth());
            g.drawLine(0, selected.getYPos(), editPanel.getHeight(), selected.getYPos());
            selected.moveBy(e.getX()-lastX, e.getY()-lastY);
            g.setXORMode(Color.black);

            g.drawLine(selected.getXPos(), 0, selected.getXPos(), editPanel.getWidth());
            g.drawLine(0, selected.getYPos(), editPanel.getHeight(), selected.getYPos());

            lastX=e.getX();
            lastY=e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    ....
}
  private class MyJButton extends JButton implements Comparable {
    private int orderIndex,idx;
    private int x, y, width, height,originx,originy;
    private String text;
    public Border DEFAULT_BORDER;// new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);
    public Border SELECT_BORDER = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3, true);

    public MyJButton(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        ....
        setFocusable(false);
    }
    public MyJButton(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height,int idx) {....}

    public void addTo(JPanel p) {
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        p.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        int x1 = x, y1 = y;
        if (x1 >= this.x && y1 >= this.y && x1 <= this.x + width && y1 <= this.y + height) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    ....
    public void moveBy(int dx, int dy) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        this.width = newWidth;
        this.height = newHeight;
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        MyJButton mjb = (MyJButton)o;
        return this.idx-mjb.idx;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Forget setSize()/setBounds/setLocation and use an appropriate `LayoutManager`. Do not use either setPreferred/setMinimum/setMaximum-size() methods. Everytime you add/remove components from a panel, just call `revalidate();repaint();` on that panel. This all works with an appropriate `LayoutManager`.

Comment: It would help if you posted a minimal program that reproduced your problem.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - would any LayoutManager work? I'm not a Swing mastermind by any means, I thought that you shouldn't use LayoutManagers when you are using setBounds() methods? I greatly appreciate your input, although I'm not sure why you gave me negative points for asking a question, albeit, to you, perhaps, a stupid one.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals - How do you mean post a minimal program? i'm happy to share the source, I just don't want to put anyone off by a particularly long post. I am looking into [link]http://pscode.org/stbc/ as we speak, maybe that will help shed some light on my problem. Thank you for your time, I appreciate your response.

Comment: "i'm happy to share the source, I just don't want to put anyone off by a particularly long post." Exactly. What you should do is post a short but complete program that reproduces/demonstrates the GUI issue you have. The idea is that I and others can troubleshoot your problem without having to read through your entire program.

Comment: @TehGoodGod Indeed, if you don't use a LayoutManager, you will have to use setBounds. What I meant was that you should always use a LayoutManager. There are very few situations where you need to bypass a LayoutManager. Have a look at the Java LayoutManager tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html and have a look at the few basic LayoutManager's embedded by default (mainly BorderLayout, GridBagLayout, FlowLayout and GridLayout). With those (and especially with the first two), you can get almost anything you want.

Comment: If you look closely, you are **Overriding** your `paint()` method in the wrong sense. `repaint()` calls are not suppose to be done from within the body of the method which is responsible for painting your GUI and other artifacts. This will lead to recursive paint calls, which is a bad practice. Also do have a look at [DRAGLAYOUT](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/), by @camickr , this might can help you loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to GagandeepBalis comment.

Okay so I found this very cool and decided to look into it more.

I came up with some logic which will be needed for it to work, maybe not the best but...:

1) We need to make our `JButton`s draggable ( thank you @camickr and his `DragLayout`) :)

2) When a `JButton`s is dragged and than dropped i.e on `mouseReleased(..)` we should check if a our dragged buttons collide with any others

3) we check whether a `JButton` collides with another by getting the JButton image and counting how many opaque pixels of the `JButton`, we are dragging, are covering another button.

4) sort the number of collisions and find the highest, this will be used so we can see where to insert the `JButton` we dragged. i.e it will be inserted by component with the most collisions.

5) sort the `ArrayList` which holds the buttons to match the changes

6) remove all buttons and re-add them using the Array (and thus they will be re-ordered).

Here is an example (Most code takes place in overridden `ComponentMover` `mouseReleased(..)` method):

Before dragging anything:

[image]

after dragging button 4 over button 1 and letting go of mouse button:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DragButtons {

    ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

    public DragButtons() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DragButtons();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseReleased(e);
                HashMap<Integer, JButton> collisions = new HashMap<>();
                JButton draggedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();

                for (JButton btn : buttons) {//iterate through all buttons and get the number of collsions of each
                    if (btn != draggedButton) {//dont chck button we were dragging
                        int col = checkPerPixelCollision(draggedButton, btn);
                        System.out.println("Button " + btn.getText());
                        System.out.println(col);
                        collisions.put(col, btn);
                    }
                }
                //lets get the button which had most collisions
                int maxCollisions = 0;
                JButton intersectingButton = null;
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, JButton> entry : collisions.entrySet()) {
                    Integer collisionCount = entry.getKey();
                    JButton button = entry.getValue();
                    if (collisionCount > maxCollisions) {
                        maxCollisions = collisionCount;
                        intersectingButton = button;
                    }
                }

                boolean reLayout = false;

                if (maxCollisions > 0) {//check if there was any
                    System.out.println("Button " + draggedButton.getText() + " is intersecting more of Button " + intersectingButton.getText());
                    System.out.println("Collisions: " + maxCollisions);
                    reLayout = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No change made");
                    reLayout = false;
                }

                ArrayList<JButton> tmpButtons = (ArrayList<JButton>) buttons.clone();//create clone of buttons

                if (reLayout) {//a button as moved and panel needs to be layed out
                    buttons.clear();//clear old buttons

                    for (JButton b : tmpButtons) {//re-order jbuttons
                        if (b == intersectingButton) {
                            buttons.add(draggedButton);
                        } else if (b == draggedButton) {
                            buttons.add(intersectingButton);
                        } else {
                            buttons.add(b);
                        }
                    }
                    panel.removeAll();//remove all buttons
                    for (JButton btn : buttons) {//iterate through all buttons and get the number of collsions of each
                        panel.add(btn);//re-add buttons according to arraylist
                    }
                    panel.revalidate();
                    panel.repaint();
                    //re-order the Array of buttons to fit
                    //remove all button and re add them using sorted array
                }

            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            buttons.add(b);
            panel.add(b);
            cm.registerComponent(b);
        }

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public HashSet<String> getMask(JButton e) {
        HashSet<String> mask = new HashSet<>();
        int pixel, a;
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            bi = componentToImage(e, e.getBounds()); //gets the current image being shown
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DragButtons.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bi.getWidth(); i++) { // for every (x,y) component in the given box, 
            for (int j = 0; j < bi.getHeight(); j++) {
                pixel = bi.getRGB(i, j); // get the RGB value of the pixel
                a = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
                if (a != 0) {  // if the alpha is not 0, it must be something other than transparent
                    mask.add((e.getX() + i) + "," + (e.getY() - j)); // add the absolute x and absolute y coordinates to our set
                }
            }
        }
        return mask;  //return our set
    }

    public static BufferedImage componentToImage(Component component, Rectangle region) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(component.getForeground());
        g.setFont(component.getFont());
        component.paintAll(g);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("c:/saved.png"));
        return img;
    }

    // Returns true if there is a collision between object a and object b   
    public int checkPerPixelCollision(JButton b, JButton b2) {
        // This method detects to see if the images overlap at all. If they do, collision is possible
        int ax1 = (int) b2.getX();
        int ay1 = (int) b2.getY();

        int ax2 = ax1 + (int) b2.getWidth();
        int ay2 = ay1 + (int) b2.getHeight();

        int bx1 = (int) b.getX();
        int by1 = (int) b.getY();

        int bx2 = bx1 + (int) b.getWidth();

        int by2 = by1 + (int) b.getHeight();

        if (by2 < ay1 || ay2 < by1 || bx2 < ax1 || ax2 < bx1) {
            return 0; // Collision is impossible.
        } else { // Collision is possible.
            // get the masks for both images
            HashSet<String> maskPlayer1 = getMask(b2);
            HashSet<String> maskPlayer2 = getMask(b);
            maskPlayer1.retainAll(maskPlayer2);  // Check to see if any pixels in maskPlayer2 are the same as those in maskPlayer1
            if (maskPlayer1.size() > 0) {  // if so, than there exists at least one pixel that is the same in both images, thus
                return maskPlayer1.size();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

class ComponentMover extends MouseAdapter {

    private Insets dragInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private Dimension snapSize = new Dimension(1, 1);
    private Insets edgeInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private boolean changeCursor = true;
    private boolean autoLayout = false;
    private Class destinationClass;
    private Component destinationComponent;
    private Component destination;
    private Component source;
    private Point pressed;
    private Point location;
    private Cursor originalCursor;
    private boolean autoscrolls;
    private boolean potentialDrag;

    /**
     * Constructor for moving individual components. The components must be
     * regisetered using the registerComponent() method.
     */
    public ComponentMover() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor to specify a Class of Component that will be moved when drag
     * events are generated on a registered child component. The events will be
     * passed to the first ancestor of this specified class.
     *
     * @param destinationClass the Class of the ancestor component
     * @param component the Components to be registered for forwarding drag
     * events to the ancestor Component.
     */
    public ComponentMover(Class destinationClass, Component... components) {
        this.destinationClass = destinationClass;
        registerComponent(components);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor to specify a parent component that will be moved when drag
     * events are generated on a registered child component.
     *
     * @param destinationComponent the component drage events should be
     * forwareded to
     * @param components the Components to be registered for forwarding drag
     * events to the parent component to be moved
     */
    public ComponentMover(Component destinationComponent, Component... components) {
        this.destinationComponent = destinationComponent;
        registerComponent(components);
    }

    /**
     * Get the auto layout property
     *
     * @return the auto layout property
     */
    public boolean isAutoLayout() {
        return autoLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Set the auto layout property
     *
     * @param autoLayout when true layout will be invoked on the parent
     * container
     */
    public void setAutoLayout(boolean autoLayout) {
        this.autoLayout = autoLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get the change cursor property
     *
     * @return the change cursor property
     */
    public boolean isChangeCursor() {
        return changeCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Set the change cursor property
     *
     * @param changeCursor when true the cursor will be changed to the
     * Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR while the mouse is pressed
     */
    public void setChangeCursor(boolean changeCursor) {
        this.changeCursor = changeCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Get the drag insets
     *
     * @return the drag insets
     */
    public Insets getDragInsets() {
        return dragInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Set the drag insets. The insets specify an area where mouseDragged events
     * should be ignored and therefore the component will not be moved. This
     * will prevent these events from being confused with a MouseMotionListener
     * that supports component resizing.
     *
     * @param dragInsets
     */
    public void setDragInsets(Insets dragInsets) {
        this.dragInsets = dragInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Get the bounds insets
     *
     * @return the bounds insets
     */
    public Insets getEdgeInsets() {
        return edgeInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Set the edge insets. The insets specify how close to each edge of the
     * parent component that the child component can be moved. Positive values
     * means the component must be contained within the parent. Negative values
     * means the component can be moved outside the parent.
     *
     * @param edgeInsets
     */
    public void setEdgeInsets(Insets edgeInsets) {
        this.edgeInsets = edgeInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Remove listeners from the specified component
     *
     * @param component the component the listeners are removed from
     */
    public void deregisterComponent(Component... components) {
        for (Component component : components) {
            component.removeMouseListener(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the required listeners to the specified component
     *
     * @param component the component the listeners are added to
     */
    public void registerComponent(Component... components) {
        for (Component component : components) {
            component.addMouseListener(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the snap size
     *
     * @return the snap size
     */
    public Dimension getSnapSize() {
        return snapSize;
    }

    /**
     * Set the snap size. Forces the component to be snapped to the closest grid
     * position. Snapping will occur when the mouse is dragged half way.
     */
    public void setSnapSize(Dimension snapSize) {
        if (snapSize.width < 1
                || snapSize.height < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Snap sizes must be greater than 0");
        }

        this.snapSize = snapSize;
    }

    /**
     * Setup the variables used to control the moving of the component:
     *
     * source - the source component of the mouse event destination - the
     * component that will ultimately be moved pressed - the Point where the
     * mouse was pressed in the destination component coordinates.
     */
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        source = e.getComponent();
        int width = source.getSize().width - dragInsets.left - dragInsets.right;
        int height = source.getSize().height - dragInsets.top - dragInsets.bottom;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(dragInsets.left, dragInsets.top, width, height);

        if (r.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            setupForDragging(e);
        }
    }

    private void setupForDragging(MouseEvent e) {
        source.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        potentialDrag = true;

        //  Determine the component that will ultimately be moved

        if (destinationComponent != null) {
            destination = destinationComponent;
        } else if (destinationClass == null) {
            destination = source;
        } else //  forward events to destination component
        {
            destination = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(destinationClass, source);
        }

        pressed = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        location = destination.getLocation();

        if (changeCursor) {
            originalCursor = source.getCursor();
            source.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }

        //  Making sure autoscrolls is false will allow for smoother dragging of
        //  individual components

        if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) destination;
            autoscrolls = jc.getAutoscrolls();
            jc.setAutoscrolls(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Move the component to its new location. The dragged Point must be in the
     * destination coordinates.
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point dragged = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        int dragX = getDragDistance(dragged.x, pressed.x, snapSize.width);
        int dragY = getDragDistance(dragged.y, pressed.y, snapSize.height);

        int locationX = location.x + dragX;
        int locationY = location.y + dragY;

        //  Mouse dragged events are not generated for every pixel the mouse
        //  is moved. Adjust the location to make sure we are still on a
        //  snap value.

        while (locationX < edgeInsets.left) {
            locationX += snapSize.width;
        }

        while (locationY < edgeInsets.top) {
            locationY += snapSize.height;
        }

        Dimension d = getBoundingSize(destination);

        while (locationX + destination.getSize().width + edgeInsets.right > d.width) {
            locationX -= snapSize.width;
        }

        while (locationY + destination.getSize().height + edgeInsets.bottom > d.height) {
            locationY -= snapSize.height;
        }

        //  Adjustments are finished, move the component

        destination.setLocation(locationX, locationY);
    }

    /*
     *  Determine how far the mouse has moved from where dragging started
     *  (Assume drag direction is down and right for positive drag distance)
     */
    private int getDragDistance(int larger, int smaller, int snapSize) {
        int halfway = snapSize / 2;
        int drag = larger - smaller;
        drag += (drag < 0) ? -halfway : halfway;
        drag = (drag / snapSize) * snapSize;

        return drag;
    }

    /*
     *  Get the bounds of the parent of the dragged component.
     */
    private Dimension getBoundingSize(Component source) {
        if (source instanceof Window) {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
            return new Dimension(bounds.width, bounds.height);
        } else {
            return source.getParent().getSize();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restore the original state of the Component
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseReleased(e);
        if (!potentialDrag) {
            return;
        }

        source.removeMouseMotionListener(this);
        potentialDrag = false;

        if (changeCursor) {
            source.setCursor(originalCursor);
        }

        if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
            ((JComponent) destination).setAutoscrolls(autoscrolls);
        }

        //  Layout the components on the parent container

        if (autoLayout) {
            if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
                ((JComponent) destination).revalidate();
            } else {
                destination.revalidate();
            }
            destination.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! and also thank you to everyone else who helped me out with your comments and replies!!! Sorry I didn't get back to you all sooner, I had to leave town for the holidays and left my work behind. I appreciate you taking your time to help me out with this and providing me with an example that accomplishes exactly what I was looking for, you guys are the best!!